# Is the "Open a window using a Visualforce page" option for a custom SObject surfaced in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-apps, lightning-experience

In Classic, we use the "Open a window using a Visualforce page" option in the "Help Settings" of our custom SObjects to link into our own help content that is included in our managed package as a static resource.

In Lightning Experience, although that option is still there in the Setup, I don't see any links to those pages in the normal UI. Is there a link somewhere that I've missed or a better alternate mechanism to mix in app-specific help pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the official answer is:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/lex_migration_whatsnew/lex_migration_whatsnew_nav_setup#Tdxn4tBK-heading15

> You can’t customize the items in the help menu. If you’ve created custom help links, those links still work from the “Help for this Page” links in the framed Salesforce Classic pages. However, your custom help links don’t appear in the new Help menu.

You could however add the Visualforce page as an Action for that object's Lightning page layout. It won't go into the same Help menu but at least it'll be somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Charles. Good advice. (A bit sad that there isn't a way to hook app help in somehow to the core help; Eclipse made handling that part of their extension model and it works well there.)